# Quart: unittest framework in Python 3.11+

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-3.11, quart

I have to the following `unittest` module for a Quart application API.  The test module works well under Python 3.10.x.  However, running under Python 3.11.x, the context seems to not be shared between setup and test methods, raising `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: camera` for each executed test method. For 3.11+ compatibility, what would the proper setup method be to ensure context (i.e. the initialized in-memory database) is shared with each asynchronous test?

```
from os import makedirs
from os import path
from quart import Quart
from unittest import IsolatedAsyncioTestCase
from unittest import main

from db import init_app
from db import get_db

def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Quart(
        __name__,
        instance_relative_config=True,
    )
    app.config.from_mapping(
        DATABASE=path.join(
            app.instance_path,
            "db.sqlite",
        ),
    )
    if test_config is None:
        app.config.from_pyfile(
        "config.py",
        silent=True,
    )
    else:
        app.config.update(test_config)
    try:
        makedirs(app.instance_path)
    except OSError:
        pass
    init_app(app)

    @app.get("/camera")
    async def list_cameras():
        rows = get_db().execute(
            "SELECT * FROM camera"
        ).fetchall()
        return list(map(dict, rows)), 200
 
    return app


class TestApp(IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.db = "file::memory:?cache=shared"
        self.app = create_app(
            {
                "DATABASE": self.db,
            }
        )
        self.client = self.app.test_client()
        runner = self.app.test_cli_runner()
        runner.invoke(args=["init-db"])

    async def asyncSetUp(self):
        self.ctx = self.app.app_context()
        await self.ctx.push()

    async def asyncTearDown(self):
        await self.ctx.pop()

    async def test_list_cameras(self):
        r = await self.client.get("/camera")
        self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 200)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```